# How to migrate mysql database to mongodb easily

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-migration

I have a website having lacks of rows, now I am planning to upgrade its database to mongoDB no SQL database.  Could any help me to find an easy way to upgrade to mondoDB with any of tools available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can export from MySQL in a CSV format and then use the Mongify tool. Just I had a few problems with handling dates of binary data.